# SQL Server : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to execute a SQL Server `SUBSTRING` query but its throwing error.

The query is:

```
select 
    substring(testcasename, 2, 5) val1, 
    substring(testcasename, 2, CHARINDEX(',', testcasename, 2) - 2) val2 
from 
    tce_lineno 
where 
    testcasename <> '' and project='proj001'
```

Error is:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Is anything wrong in this query?

Comment: this `CHARINDEX(',',testcasename,2)` part returned `0` that's why. When `testcasename` does not have `,` then your code will fail

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments When `testcasename` does not have `,` then `CHARINDEX(',',testcasename,2)` will return `0` so `Substring` will fail.

To fix that use `case` statement, When `,` is not found use length of `testcasename`

```
SELECT Substring(testcasename, 2, 5)   val1,
       Substring(testcasename, 2, CASE
                                    WHEN Charindex(',', testcasename, 2) > 2 THEN Charindex(',', testcasename, 2) - 2
                                    ELSE Len(testcasename)
                                  END) val2
FROM   tce_lineno
WHERE  testcasename <> ''
       AND project = 'proj001'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this clause to where

And testcasename like '%,%'

Error happens because some of the records does not have comma (,) in it